# How to configure the height of 'Insert Character' popup window in OOTB Tridion 2011 SP1?

Tags: popup, tridion, tridion-2011

RTF Field --> Insert special character. We have added few more special characters to the list.
We have a requirement to increase the height of the popup window.Where can we configure it ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not something you can do via Configuration file.

However, you can locate
*\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Scripts\Cme.js
and find `SPECIALCHAR_POPUP` definition,

Then you could change popup `FEATURES: "width=350px,height=300px,resizable=1"` according to your needs.

Comment: I am certain this will work, but keep in mind that changing the JS files from the CME might violate your support contract.

Comment: @ChrisSummers, that's true. Another way of doing this:

* Create new js file, which overrides this one particular property

* Create new extension and group in configuration with this new js file

* Extend group, which contains Cme.js with your extension group

Still sounds like workaround, but initial files will not be modified